# get content of a file and replace multiple values on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

`test.php`
lorem blue ipsum red

```
$str = file_get_contents('test.php');
$new_str = str_replace(['blue','red'], ['green','gold'], $str);
echo $new_str;  // lorem green ipsum gold
```

I need the same on client side

```
var str = content of test.php  // how to get this
var new_str = str.replace(...) // how to replace multiple values
console.log(new_str);  // lorem green ipsum gold
```

Any help?

Comment: Where is the file? On the server? The client? What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make a `fetch` request to your server to get the file and read it's contents, so you could do something like the following

```js
fetch("./test.php")
  .then(function (result) {
    return result.text();
  })
  .then(function (content) {
    var replacements = [
      ["blue", "red"],
      ["green", "gold"],
    ];
    var final = content;

    for (var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
      var pairs = replacements[i];
      var replace = pairs[0];
      var replaceWith = pairs[1];

      final = final.replace(replace, replaceWith);
    }
    console.log("final", final);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Assuming your `test.php` file has the following content:

```
lorem blue ipsum red
```

Running the code snippet above, the result will be:

```
lorem red ipsum red
```

Comment: That won't give you the contents of the file, that's not how PHP works. This is a *guess*, not an answer. Your edit didn't fix it either. PHP does not return file contents by default, you have to `echo` them.

Comment: @JaredSmith what fix are you talking about specifically? And have you tried this exact code snippet with a `test.php` file that has the exact content like the OP is providing? Because I have and it works.

Comment: @goto1, thanks, I believe it works, but I will wait for a potentially simpler solution

Comment: @qadenza what's difficult about this solution?

Comment: @goto1 just a lot of lines compared to php. Maybe something like `hiden_div.load('test.php'); var str = hiden_div.html()...` I'm not sure

Comment: @qadenza client-side `JavaScript` and server-side `PHP` are two different environments - you can't just read any local file in client-side `JavaScript` the way you want it because of security reasons, you will have to `fetch` it, or something similar, like in the example above.

Comment: @goto1 fetching the content is ok, but once it's fetched I hope there is a simpler way to replace substrings. If no - I will accept you solution.

Comment: @qadenza I changed it to a simple `for loop` and got rid of the `Array.reduce` method.

Comment: @goto1 what was the purpose of `reduce`, pls

Comment: @qadenza `Array.prototype.reduce` allows you to iterate through each element of an array and produce a single output value, so it worked well in this case as you have to iterate through an array of replacements and produce a final/single string with all replaced substrings. See here for more if needed - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce